# I can't calculate and compare the hash of each file in a folder

Tags: python

I have a hashcomparator.py python script, which in the script opens a folder and then should calculate the hash of each file, open the second folder, calculate the hash of the files and then compare the hashes

```
import hashlib
import glob

#Open the input folder
path = "C:\\Users\\luis.henrique\\Documents\\filesin\\"
#scrolls through all .txt files
filesin = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "**/*.txt", recursive=True)]
#calculate hash of .txt files
hash_object = hashlib.sha256(b'filesin')
hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()

#Open the output folder
path = "C:\\Users\\luis.henrique\\Documents\\filesout\\"
#scrolls through all .txt files
filesout = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "**/*.txt", recursive=True)]
#calculate hash of .txt files
hash_object = hashlib.sha256(b'filesout')
hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()

if filesin == filesout: 
    print ("The MD5 Hashes of the files are the same.")
    print  (filesin)
    print(hex_dig)
    print  ("\n")
    print  (filesout)
    print(hex_dig)
else:
    print ("The MD5 Hashes are not the same.")
    print(hex_dig)
```

But I can't calculate and compare the hash of each file.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What's the output compared to your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are constructing lists of files with glob, but then you are not sending these to the hashlib function. You are instead passing a string 'filesin'.  You're going to have to feed each file, taking care not to exceed the buffer size. This should get you started:

```
for file in filesin:
    sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256()
    with open(file,'rb') as f:
        # Read and update hash string value in blocks of 4K
        for byte_block in iter(lambda: f.read(4096),b""):
            sha256_hash.update(byte_block)
        print(sha256_hash.hexdigest())
```